# Subscribe to Event which does not have an event name

Tags: php, events, shopware

I try to subscribe to the Event in Shopware 6.3.5

```
\Shopware\Core\Content\ImportExport\Event\ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent
```

The class does not define an EVENT_NAME, which I seem to need according to the docs:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    // Return the events to listen to as array like this:  <event to listen to> => <method to execute>
    return [
        ProductEvents::PRODUCT_LOADED_EVENT => 'onProductsLoaded'
    ];
}
```

What do I enter as array key for the subscribed events now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple - use the class name:

```
use Shopware\Core\Content\ImportExport\Event\ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent;

...

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent::class 
            => 'onImportExportBeforeImportRecord'
    ];
}
```